# get data from a Db display in combobox in java

Tags: java, database, jdbc

hi everyone i have this code but don't know why it doesn't work!

```
rset = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT categoryName FROM DB_Library.dbo.categories");
while (rset.next()) {
    String s = rset.getString("categoryName");
    jComboBox1.addItem(rset.getString(s).trim());
}
```

don't show me any thing 
* This code is printing all the items in database:

```
rset = stmt.executeQuery("select * from DB_Library.dbo.categories");
while (rset.next()) {
    String s = rset.getString("categoryName");
    System.out.println(s );
}
```

any help?

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
rset = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT categoryName FROM DB_Library.dbo.categories");
while (rset.next())
{
    String s = rset.getString("categoryName");
    jComboBox1.addItem(s.trim());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The combobox items must be loaded before it is painted in the screen.

Comment: hmm i use netbeans6.9.1 i was designed my app interface in Jframe manually,isn't add auto?